# React Native: Refs in ListView

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

It looks like the refs of views in is hard to be directly accessed.

Now I have a list view with a cells. In the `renderRow` function I have something like:

```
renderRowView: function(rowData){
  return 
    <View >
        <TextInput
           ref="text"
        />
    </View>
},
```

In this case, if I want to access this TextInput using ref, it will be `undefined`.

I saw a thread on Github (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/897) mentioned about a way to resolve this, but I still couldn't understand how to use it:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData, sec, i) =>
        <Text ref={(row) => this.rows[sec][i] = row}>{rowData}</Text>
       }
    />
  );
},
```

Please help me understand how this ref function works, and how to use it (i.e. programmatically focus on the `TextInput` in the row.). Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ref` attribute on a React Component can either be a `string` or a `callback` function, which will be called with the component in its first argument.

So passing a function to a `ref` attribute will execute it when the component is mounted, with the component itself in the first argument.

What the github code you pasted is doing is adding the component to a two-dimensional array when it's mounted via the `ref` callback attribute. The `row` argument is essentially the `<TextInput/>` itself.

What do you want to achieve ? There might be an easier and cleaner solution.

---

**EDIT:** Regarding what you're trying to achieve, this would work :

```
render: function() {

    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) => {
                var inputRefs = [];

                var _focusInput = function(name) {
                    inputRefs[name].focus();
                };

                var input1 =
                    <TextInput 
                        ref={(input) => {
                            inputRefs['input1'] = input;
                        }}
                        onSubmitEditing={_focusInput.bind(null, 'input2')}
                        onEndEditing={_focusInput.bind(null, 'input2')} />;


                var input2 =
                    <TextInput 
                        ref={(input) => {
                            inputRefs['input2'] = input;
                        }} />;

                return (
                    <View>
                        {input1}
                        {input2}
                    </View>
                );
            }}/>
    );
}
```

You can dive more into TextInput events there https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#content.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @whitep4nther. Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is: there's a ListView, and each cell has a TextInput. When user focus and edit one TextInput, press "done" or "next" button can automatically focus on the next TextInput. I assume I need to use `ref` to get the next input, and programmatically set focus.

Comment: I see, this is a very clear solution. Thank you very much!