# React Native - get refs of custom components in listview from renderRow

Tags: react-native, ref, react-native-listview

I have a ListView and am trying to access the refs of custom components I have written in the renderRow. I need to do some direct manipulation of the custom components so I need to get the refs of these.

It seems like other people have faced this issue too. I have tried following the recommendations in [React Native: Refs in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382431/react-native-refs-in-listview) and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/897 but they don't seem to work for me. I have tried using the callback ref method as suggested. But, when I try printing out this.refs.listView.refs in componentDidMount, it is empty instead of returning customRef. How do I get the refs of the custom components from the renderRow function? Thank you

The class has the following functions:

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.refs.listView.refs);
},

getRef() {
   return 'customRef';
},

renderRow(rowData) {
   return (
     <CustomComponent ref={(ref)=>this.getRef} key={rowData.key} />
   );
},

render() {
   return (
      <ListView
         ref={'listView'}
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={this.renderRow} />
   );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a syntactical error in your code:

```
renderRow(rowData) {
   return (
     //                                     \/ Missing execution of getRef
     <CustomComponent ref={(ref)=>this.getRef} key={rowData.key} />
   );
},
```

Second, the ref callback function has to actually store the ref somewhere to be referenced when you call `this.refs.listView.refs`.  Where do you expect this value to come from?  React doesn't allow for this sort of magical child ref storage, it's totally manual.  You get a ref to this particular component in your callback, you have to figure out what to do with it.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.rowRefs = [];
    this.storeRowRef = this.storeRowRef.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.rowRefs.length);
}
storeRowRef(rowRef) {
    this.rowRefs.push(rowRef);
}
renderRow(rowData) {
   return (
     <CustomComponent ref={storeRowRef} key={rowData.key} />
   );
},
...
```