# how to access react-native listview child components through ref?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

***how to access react-native [listview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) child components through ref?***

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6']),
    };
  }

  onTap() {
    console.log(this.refs)
    /* After getting touchComponent refs below block of code has to be executed.
    that.refs.touchComponent.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
    this.setState({
       isVisible: true,
       buttonRect: {x: px, y: py, width: width, height: height}
    });
  });
  */
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView ref="listView"
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <TouchableHighlight ref="touchComponent" onPress={this.onTap.bind(this)}><Text>{rowData}</Text></TouchableHighlight>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

`console.log(this.refs)` ***prints*** `Object {listView: Object}`

***how can i access `TouchableHighlight` component ref?***

*I gone through [React Native: Refs in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382431/react-native-refs-in-listview) and [React Native - get refs of custom components in listview from renderRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258143/react-native-get-refs-of-custom-components-in-listview-from-renderrow) but i don't understand how they are doing.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant access refs through the string way of adding refs inside ListView you have to use the callback technique to apply refs

```
 <ListView ref="listView"
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <TouchableHighlight ref={(TouchableHighLight) => { this.button = TouchableHighLight; }} onPress={this.onTap.bind(this)}><Text>{rowData}</Text></TouchableHighlight>}
      />
```

But most probably even after getting the ref you wont be able to access the measure method. To obtain pageX and pageY you can pass the touch event with the onPress and use nativeEvent to obtain the pageX and pageY like this ,you can obtain width and height using measureInWindow method:-

```
onPress={(event) => this.onTap(event)}
```

method definition could be something like this:-

```
onTap(evnt) {
  var py=evnt.nativeEvent.pageY
  var px=evnt.nativeEvent.pageX
  console.log(this.refs)
this.button.measureInWindow(x,y,width,height)
  this.setState({
       isVisible: true,
       buttonRect: {x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height}
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to access the element tapped:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Text,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.buildList = this.buildList.bind(this)
    this.onTap = this.onTap.bind(this)

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.rows = []
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        {id: 0, text: 'row 1'},
        {id: 1, text: 'row 2'},
        {id: 2, text: 'row 3'},
        {id: 3, text: 'row 4'},
        {id: 4, text: 'row 5'},
        {id: 5, text: 'row 6'}

      ]),
    };
  }

  onTap(id) {
    console.log(this.rows[id])
 }

  buildList (data) {
    const onRowTap = () => this.onTap(data.id)
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight key={data.id} ref={row => this.rows[data.id] = row} onPress={onRowTap}>
          <Text style={{color: '#000', padding: 20}}>{data.text}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView style={{marginTop: 50}} ref="listView"
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.buildList}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Is the same concept as the link you posted but maybe this way is easier to understand.
Instead of trying to get rows from class refs you create an empty array in the class scope and fill it with rows while building the list. Then you simply pass an id on tap to the press function and you can get you tapped row. They do the same way just going deep into the `listView` refs because actually the rows are `ListeView` children so you to refer to the `ListView`refs and not your `Class`refs