# React Native : ListView with TextInput in each row

Tags: listview, react-native, textinput

I'm trying to pass on to the nextResponder(TextInput) available in a ListView component on react-native.

I found this solution to implement it : [React Native: Refs in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382431/react-native-refs-in-listview)

But using this I can only switch to ONE next textInput, after that the keyboard is dismissed when I click on 'next'.

I know that the focus method works, and I've seen many examples where people have multiple TextInput and they focus the next one by using refs.

My problem is my listview's number of rows is dynamic and I can't add all of the TextInput manually.

I tried using the sectionID attribute of the renderRow method which gives me the index of each row, but I can't seem to connect to the next TextInput.

For your information, here is my current code :

```
renderInput(rowData, rowID, sectionID) {
  var inputRefs = [];
  var _focusInput = function(name) {
   inputRefs[name].focus();
  };
  var index = 0
  var input1 =
               <TextInput
                 placeholder={'Enter your input'}
                 blurOnSubmit={false}
                 ref={(input) => {
                  inputRefs[index] = input;
                    }}
                 onSubmitEditing={_focusInput.bind(null, index + 1)}
                 onEndEditing={_focusInput.bind(null, index + 1)} />;

  var input2 =
               <TextInput
                 placeholder={'Enter your input'}
                 blurOnSubmit={false}
                 ref={(input) => {
                       inputRefs[index + 1] = input;
                   }} />;

 return (
   <View>
      {input1}
      {input2}
   </View>
 );
}
```

I hope one brilliant mind can lead me to the right direction!

Cheers

Comment: To anyone who would like to know, I managed to find a solution myself using a global array of refs in my component, and focusing the next input with onSubmitEditing.

Comment: Could you post the full solution as answer

Comment: I'm doing an arrays of refs[] too, but I always got undefined for next index's of my List even if the very first item works well if I do refs.myFirstRow.focus()...